# Постановка запятых: обособление обстоятельств, предлог В ЗАВИСИМОСТИ ОТ

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги, обстоятельство, обстоятельственный-оборот

> Для написания качественной биографии и понимания внутриигрового мира(,) стоит ознакомиться с...

Увидел, как там поставили запятую, но причин не понимаю. Это ошибка или есть правило?

> Важно понимать, что(,) в зависимости от расы(,) к вам будут по-разному относится жители разных локаций.

Будет ли здесь выделяться эта часть? И в каких случаях она выделяется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Для написания качественной биографии и понимания внутриигрового мира стоит ознакомиться с...**

Обычно обстоятельства цели не обособляются. Не вижу причин для обособления и здесь.

2. **Важно понимать, что(,) в зависимости от расы(,) к вам будут по-разному относится жители разных [локаций?]**

Тут обособление необязательно, но, на мой взгляд, желательно.

> [В ЗАВИСИМОСТИ ОТ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_800) (чего), предлог
>   Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «в зависимости от», могут обособляться. О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания ([Прил. 1](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1))
>
> Обычно обособляются обороты, которые... находятся не в начале и не в конце предложения.

Примечание. Слово *локация* здесь использовано, на мой взгляд, неверно.

Comment: Речь об описании компьютерной игры для любителей компьютерных игр, поэтому слово "локация" здесь вполне уместно.